# what are my options for viewing my ad user groups?

Tags: powershell, security, active-directory, ldap

I need to find out which groups my AD user belongs to. I followed the instructions in the following url but I don't have enough access rights on my machine to do this:

https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-see-which-group-your-windows-user-belongs-to/

If I search through the "Find Users, Contacts and Groups" dialog then I can find my User but it doesn't appear that this dialog gives me the ability to find the groups associated with my AD user. Do I have any other options that I can use to identify the groups associated with my AD user?

Answer (score 0):

Start a Powershell session and run the following:

```
net user <username> /domain
```

Where  is the name of your user without any domain prefix e.g.,

```
net user adam /domain
```

Anything that supplies the plain old user name works too as noted...

```
net user $env:username /domain
net user [Environment]::UserName /domain
```

A-

Comment: That didn't work for me - `net user` doesn't like the name format `whoami` outputs.  This works, though: `net user $env:UserName /domain`

Comment: Lol! Of course it didn’t. Sorry, sent this from my phone on the way  home. Updated my answer to correct.

Answer (score 0):

What about just doing something like any of the following...

```
### Show User and AD group membership

# Get users with all their properties and their group membership, display user and group name

ForEach ($TargetUser in (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *))
{
"`n" + "-"*12 + " Showing group membership for " + $TargetUser.SamAccountName
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $TargetUser.SamAccountName `
| Select Name
}

# Get users with base properties and their group membership, display user and group name

ForEach ($TargetUser in (Get-ADUser -Filter *))
{
"`n" + "-"*12 + " Showing group membership for " + $TargetUser.SamAccountName
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $TargetUser.SamAccountName `
| Select Name
}

# Get user and AD group info, display user and group name

Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com" `
-SearchScope OneLevel -Properties Name, MemberOf `
| Select-Object Name, @{Label="Memberof";
expression={($_.memberof `
| Get-ADGroup `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -Join ","}}

Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -SearchBase "CN=users,DC=contoso,DC=com" `
-SearchScope OneLevel -Properties Name, MemberOf |
Select-Object Name, @{Label="Memberof";
expression={($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -Join ","}} `
| Format-List
```

Of course format as needed.